# How can I drop rows from a DataFrame that have a duplicate strings across multiple columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with multiple columns which must all be a unique string for that particular row to be valid (i.e. in my example below, I have 4 columns, so must have 4 unique values).  I therefore want to drop any row that contains a duplicate string in any of the columns.

Feels like it should be straight forward, but I can't figure it out.  Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([['a','b','c','d'],['a','c','d','c'],['b','a','e','g'],['a','a','c','f'],['b','c','b','d']],columns=['Pos1','Pos2','Pos3','Pos4'])


print(df)

  Pos1 Pos2 Pos3 Pos4
0    a    b    c    d
1    a    c    d    c
2    b    a    e    g
3    a    a    c    f
4    b    c    b    d


The output I want will drop row index 1 ('c' is repeated), row index 3 ('a' is repeated) and row index 4 ('b' is repeated)


  Pos1 Pos2 Pos3 Pos4
0    a    b    c    d
2    b    a    e    g
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check number of unique values per rows by [`DataFrame.nunique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.nunique.html) and compare by number of columns by [`Series.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html) (`==`) for filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = df[df.nunique(axis=1).eq(len(df.columns))]
print (df)
  Pos1 Pos2 Pos3 Pos4
0    a    b    c    d
2    b    a    e    g
```

Comment: Thanks jezrael.  That is exactly how I was thinking about it, I just couldn't find the code to execute!